# swift login form not corresponding with background

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I am developing an app and I am currently working on the login page and I cannot get the Textfields and buttons to line up with the backgrounds. The app only uses portrait view.

[iPhone 7s plus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lxdpo.png)

If there are any more questions ask me and I can answer those.

[Login Page without buttons or textfields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHYLZ.png)

Comment: Have you applied constraints?

Comment: yes I have tried but they look all weird and do not fix it, also I am not that good with constraints maybe you have a link or something I can use to help me?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html

Comment: Thanks I am checking that out now

Comment: Can't seem to get the constraints working maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: Can you show the full background image you are using? (without any buttons or labels or textfields)

Comment: Just updated added a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will likely be continuously frustrated trying to match up your text fields, labels and buttons with a "full screen" background image, simply because of the differences in screen dimensions.

I think you'll be much better off using:

- a plain background gradient
- the "logo" image with transparent background
- the text-entry "box" + fields as a custom view
- buttons as buttons

Then, use constraints (and possibly a `UIStackView` or two) to arrange those elements relative to each other.

Comment: Ok I'll try that out

Comment: By the way... you will want to constrain your elements *centered* horizontally. **NOT** 24-pts from the left and 280-pts width (for example).

Comment: Ok thanks I think you answered what I was looking for

Answer (score -1):

You could try for the constraints, which could make your app use for any of the modes (landscape or portrait).Try referring to this video it is really helpful

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7iT9fueKCJM.

Comment: I'm checking it out now

Comment: Just checked out the video, my app is only going to be in portrait and not in landscape I just need my page to fit to other devices.

Comment: Why dont you make your app universal instead of going for an iphone or an ipad. ?

Comment: It is universal i just can't get the constraints to make it so that if your on iPhone 5s you can go to iPhone 7s, everything gets displaced